# How can I Space the Section Titles away from Section number in Content Page?

Tags: table-of-contents

Currently I am using:

```
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
```

And it is making the section number and section title overlap. Is there a way of putting more space between the two and keeping the style of the Content page?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome, which class are you using?

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Looks like a job for `tocloft` or for changing `\l@section` (or `\l@chapter`)

Answer (score 1):

If `book.cls` is used, the change can be done very easily with `tocloft` and adding some extra length value to the `\cftchapnumwidth` length variable, increasing the space for the number box in the `ToC` for chapter numbers. If `article` is used, there's `\cftsecnumwidth` or `\cftpartnumwidth`.

The value of `10pt` is very arbitrary. Please change to an appropiate value!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{6}

\chapter{Mrs. Premise}
\chapter{Mrs. Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

[image]